# Stopping renderer in springy.js library

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Is there anyone has used [springy.js](https://github.com/dhotson/springy) library?

I would like to ask after I started a renderer by `renderer.start();`, **how to stop it?** Seems there is only `start()` function defined for the renderer object but there is no `stop()` function...

Answer (score 0):

There is a `settimeout()` function in the library, you just need to create a stop function, which is used to kill the `settimeout()` function with the given id.